# How likely is it for Selmer groups to have mu invariant 0?

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves, iwasawa-theory

Given a number field $K$, how likely is it that we'll find at least one elliptic curve $E/K$ such that the $\mu$-invariant of its Selmer group is 0 (in a cyclotomic extension)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose you did not fix $p$, but you fixed $K$. I think that it is easier to find an elliptic curve with $\mu=0$ than to find an elliptic curve with rank zero and finite Tate-Shafarevich group. Indeed, if $E$ has rank zero and Sha is finite, then there is a prime $p$ such that

- $E$ has good ordinary non-anomalous reduction at all primes above $p$
- The $p$-primary part of Sha is trivial
- No Tamagawa number is divisible by $p$

(The lower two are ok and I would believe there is an argument for the top one, too. But I have not tought about it.)
It then follows that the $p$-primary Selmer group for that $E$ over the cyclotomic $\mathbb{Z}_p$-extension is finitely generated and torsion. The conditions imply that the leading term (=constant term) of the charactersitic series is a unit and hence the Selmer group is finite - and that is much more than just $\mu=0$.

If you wish to fix $p$, then you need to find a rank $0$ curve for which the above list of conditions holds. In any case, none of this can be done unconditionally because of the required finiteness of Sha.

I cannot see any easy way to show that $\mu=0$ other than showing that the Selmer group is finite alltogether. Conjecturally, for any given elliptic curve $E/K$ of any rank, the leading term of the $p$-adic charactersitic series is a unit for the vast majority of primes $p$ of good ordinary reduction (because of how we expect $p$-adic heights to be distributed). That still implies $\mu=0$. Therefore the answer to the question in the title is very very likely.

Comment: I didn't know this but I realized that there is a paper of Mazur-Rubin (2010) where they prove that given a number field $K$, there is always an elliptic curve $E/K$ such that it has rank 0. In fact, they say something much stronger, they say $E(K)=0$.

Comment: Yes, this is done by showing the 2-Selmer group is trivial. Presumably that gives you examples with $\mu=0$ for $p=2$.

Comment: I am curious what happens at anomalous primes (assuming finiteness of Sha). Mazur's example of elliptic curves of conductor 11 at $p=5$ suggests that $\mu$ can be 0 or positive. Is it only at anomalous primes that we expect $\mu$ to be positive? 

When $E(\mathbb{Q})[p]$ is trivial, Mazur shows that the $p$-primary part of $Sel(E/\mathbb{Q}_\infty)$ is infinite, and there are some similar results for number fields too. But can rank 0 elliptic curves over $K$ have finite $p$-primary part of $Sel(E/K_\infty)$ if $p$ is an anomalous prime and $E(K)[p]$ is non-trivial?

Comment: As far as I know there are results which
prove that the dual Selmer over the cyclotomic extension has no nonzero finite  
submodules. So if the Selmer group is finite, then they are zero. Am I correct in saying that or am I missing something?

Comment: I think you need that the torsion in $E(K)$ is trivial for this. So if you add that to the list above then yes, the Selmer group is trivial alltogether. But that was not the original question here.